# Casting to another property in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a combobox which is structured like this:

```
  public class PersonDataQueryField
  {
        public string FriendlyName { get; set; }
        public IList<string> XPaths { get; set; }
        public Type DataType { get; set; }
  }
```

A list of this class exist in my ViewModel, and bound to a Combobox, with the `DisplayMemeberPath=FriendlyName`. I have several `DataTemplates` in my View, which will trigger based upon the selected `DataType` in the `Combobox` to fill the `ContentControl`. To the right of this combobox a `TextBox` exist where the user can enter a SearchQuery. The `Text` property is of type `object` and meant to be casted to the `SelectedPersonDataQueryField.DataType` when the user presses "Search".

```
var searchQuery = (SelectedSearchQueryParameter.DataType) SearchQuery;
```

This is not allowed since `SelectedSearchQueryParameter` is a `Property` and not a `Type`, but the `DataType` is `Type`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What would you expect to do with that (`searchQuery`) afterwards? The point of a cast is usually to allow you to use certain members of that type in the code that follows - if you don't know what type it is at compile-time, what members are you going to try to use?

Comment: Would this not be better achieved by using a DataTemplateSelector, which could evaluate the TextBox content, and switch the relevant template? Or, as @JonSkeet asks, do you have a need to use specific members on the cast DataType?

Comment: The `searchQuery`variable is supposed to be sent to a `facade` whic h can accept any type, further down to a `repository` and finally to a WCF service. I might need reconsider the design..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd agree with Jon. Though, this is how:

```
dynamic searchQuery = Convert.ChangeType(SearchQuery, 
                           SelectedSearchQueryParameter.DataType);
```

but why, and what's next :p?